# Change from character to numeric without changing dimensions in R

Tags: r

I am calculating module preservation on R with WGCNA by following their tutorial, but I can't run the actual calculation, because it returns an error that it can only do it with numeric data. Sure enough, when I checked:

```
>is.numeric(datExprCTL)
[1] FALSE
>dim(datExprCTL)
[1] 185 2225
```

So I did the only thing I know to change it, but this is what happened:

```
>datExprCTL<-as.numeric(datExprCTL)    
>dim(datExprCTL)
NULL
```

And when I run my module preservation script, it does say: Error in colSums(!is.na(datExpr[useSamples, useGenes])) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

So, my question is how can I convert to numeric without losing the dimensions and going ahead with module preservation, which needs to have the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
storage.mode(datExprCTL) <- "numeric"
```

Comment: this may be a duplicate but posting the answer was easier than looking for the dupe :-(

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.